# Check overall progress of file upload of jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I need to check overall progress of the [Jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

I'm allowing my users to upload multiple files, Now I want to know what all the files are completed then I need to trigger a function to do some other work.

I tried all the callbacks  but couldn't figure it out.

I even tried this
 `var activeUploads = $('.new_photographer').fileupload('active');`

But its variable is returning some garbage data.
Here's my jquery:

```
$('.new_photographer').fileupload({
  dataType :'json',
  fileInput: $(this).find('input:file'),
  acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|png|jpg)$/i,
  dropZone: $(this).find('#dropzone'),
  complete : function (e, data) {
    var activeUploads = $('.new_photographer').fileupload('active');
    var overallProgress = $('.new_photographer').fileupload('progress');

    alert(JSON.stringify(activeUploads));
    //alert('overallProgress :: '+JSON.stringify(overallProgress));
    if ( activeUploads < 0){
      window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
  }
}).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
  var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
  data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
});
```

Comment: did you already experiment with the given `done` and `progressall` functions from the demo (at the bottom of basic.html)?

Comment: @ho.s Yeah its returning some garbage data.